# Only activate web sharing that I can use virtualhost with apache on Mac OS

Tags: apache, virtualhost, osx-server

I have configure httpd.conf and httpd-vhosts.conf, when I active the web sharing the virtualhost is useful, but when I close web sharing and start apache, the virtualhost doesn't work

Here is my virtualhost config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/Users/lch/Sites"
        ServerName myhome.com
</VirtualHost>
<Directory "/User/lch/Sites">
        Options None
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

And, here is error short-cut:

I am a newer for Mac OS, and I come from china.
Thank you for read my question.

Comment: Maybe it's better to ask your question at serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check:

1. Is the include for httpd-vhosts.conf uncommented in httpd.conf? I believe it's commented out by default.
2. Have you added myhome.com to your hosts file? Make sure you've got the following entry in /etc/hosts: `127.0.0.1 myhome.com`